# Name or author of tiling geometric pattern?

Tags: patterns, style-identification, style

The image given design is very impressive and I really liked the designs used as background images and decoration.

Is there a name for this design and author?

[image]

Comment: Isometric tiles are used from ancient times (see also [here](https://www.google.it/search?q=ancient+roma+tiles&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAlqzY8-zKAhVCRg8KHcUKC-gQ_AUIBygB&biw=1680&bih=927)).

Comment: I think you can safely assume that the author of this one has passed away more than 60, 600 or 1600 years ago :). This is public domain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a licence or a specific creator for this geometric pattern.

But I found it **[here](https://www.shutterstock.com/pic.mhtml?utm_medium=Affiliate&utm_campaign=FindIcons.com&tpl=38925-43068&id=49628389&utm_source=38925&irgwc=1&language=en)**:

There are many variations of this patterns, like this one

[image]

[source](https://www.shutterstock.com/pic-49641028/stock-vector-seamless-geometric-pattern.html?src=pp-same_artist-49628389-4&ws=1)

I honestly think you can recreate this by yourself and use it freely...

Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Its a old pattern... old enough for us to have forgotten the original author.

Answer (score 0):

One similar example is the traditional, Japanese Bishamon-Kikkō, Bishamon tortoiseshell or "Bishamon's armor" motif. Traditional examples can be angular or curved but you can find many variations including ones near-identical to your posted image.

There is no universal western name for this pattern but there are terms that define it accurately. It is a seamless/tileable, geometric, isometric, tesselation.

Some stock websites also use the terms "3D" or "optical illusion", although this is usually reserved for shaded versions that simulate a distant, uniform light source.
As others have stated it is a very old pattern, seen in multiple cultures, and is most certainly part of the public domain.

[image: bishamon-kikko sashiko]